# What did the Greeks and Romans believe about language relationships?

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, indo-european, history, greek

The ancient Greeks and Romans had no concept of historical linguistics or of the Indo-European language family. However, it would have been noticeable to anyone who spoke even a little of both Greek and Latin that they shared many similarities, most obviously in basic vocabulary such as kinship terms and numerals, but also in some of the inflectional endings. Further afield, there would have been some scholars or travelers who had knowledge of other IE languages, such as Persian, or even of Indic or Germanic languages, and who could easily have noticed the same similarities (while, on the other hand, someone familiar with a non-IE language -- Semitic, Etruscan -- could have seen that these shared features were absent there). What did they think the reason for this was? Do we have any surviving writings that address the question of why these languages have so much in common?

My guess would be that anyone thinking about this question in those times would have done so in a 'genealogy of peoples' framework, where e.g. the Romans were descended from the Trojans, etc., and tried to explain the linguistic facts that way. But do we actually know?

Comment: The same was probably true in other parts of the world, and at other times. So there is no reason to restrict the question to Greeks and Romans.

Comment: Yes, I'd be very interested in answers about other ancient civilizations, too!

Comment: In India, it was and still is obvious that Sanskrit was the source of all languages, and any I-E relations simply pointed out how true that was. Greeks and Romans probly assumed Latin was a degenerate version of Greek, the prior civilization. Nobody did anything systematic about it, though, until the 19th century.

Comment: I was also thinking of medieval intellectual. Though the fact that they worked in Latin, and probably held common language in low esteem, probably did not help reflection on these issues.

Comment: Very few intellectuals in medieval western Europe actually knew Greek, so they would probably have been worse placed than the ancients to figure out the relationship. It was really only with the Renaissance that Greek became widely known in western Europe. But even then it took a couple of centuries for anyone to recognize there was an IE language family (van Boxhorn in the 17C). The Byzantines would have been well acquainted with both languages, though; I wonder what they thought.

Comment: Sanskrit makes the situation clear, though. To a first approximation, PIE is Sanskrit consonants with Greek vowels. The PIE consonants have been smeared and compacted in Greek, and especially Latin, whereas the Sanskrit vowel system is clearly vastly changed from PIE.

Comment: Right, and there was lots of contact between Greeks and Indians from Alexander on. People on both sides must have had theories about the similarities; I wonder if anything has survived.

Comment: @jlawler: In India, it was and still is obvious that Sanskrit was not the source of Kannada, Malayalam, Tamil, or Telugu. That's only a couple of hundred million people to ignore today, and I'm sure even easier to ignore back in the past.

Comment: That just gave the Aryans more reason to officially ignore Dravidian languages as infra dig, but not before they borrowed many Dravidian features, like the retroflex consonant system.

Comment: @jlawler *Greeks and Romans probly assumed Latin was a degenerate version of Greek, the prior civilization.* I do not believe this is true. While the Greek civilisation was older and more venerable, and Latin picked up some features from Greek, it was still seen as very old and not a descendent of Greek. Moreover, conservative Romans always saw the Greek civilisation as somewhat decadent and Asian (sic): the purity and rigour of *Latinitas* (Greek had neither) were praised and fairly strictly enforced in literature, depending on circumstances. (Note that *Latinitas* is a complex notion.)

Comment: This is not a technical answer but you might be interested in "Creation" by Gore Vidal.

Comment: Please summarise the book(?), or else this will probably be deleted.

Comment: curiousdannii:  Wikipedia "The story follows the adventures of a fictional "Cyrus Spitama", an Achaemenid Persian diplomat of the 6th-5th century BCE who travels the known world comparing the political and religious beliefs of various empires of the time"   As I remember the book, there was a section in which Spitama discusses the migrations into India and Europe and the common origin of the languages of India, Persia and Greece.  Although this is "just" a novel, the author knows a lot about the ancient world, cf "Julian".  This is Vidal's take on what a well-traveled ancient would know.

Comment: @TKR The New Testament was habitually read in Greek until the standardisation of the Latin NT at the Council of Trent. The best medieval grammar schools taught Greek along with Latin. Universities (e.g. Cambridge & Bologna) certainly did. William of Moerbeke could translate into Greek. The popularisation of Hermeneutics had more to do with sola scriptura Protestantism than the Renaissance.

Comment: @slipperyiron, thanks, that's interesting. Still, the Vulgate would have been much more widely known, right? Maybe I'm underestimating the extent of Greek knowledge in medieval Western Europe, but it's my impression that whereas knowledge of Latin was a sine qua non of basic education, this was far from the case with Greek.

Comment: @TKR Yes. You are correct. All knew Latin but many also knew enough Greek to read it. "Very few" is underwhelming. Some faculty members would have had to know Greek (and Hebrew) nevermind the intellectuals we know enough to remember.

Answer (score 17):

The Greeks had most probably noticed a similarity of their language with **Phrygian**. Socrates at least did so while speaking to Hermogenes: "*Well then, consider whether this pyr is not foreign ; for the word is not easily brought into relation with the Hellenic tongue, and the Phrygians may be observed to have the same word slightly changed, just as they have ydor (water) and kynes (dogs), and many other words*". They also noticed that their language had changed, compared to the language(s) spoken in Greece in (the period they considered) ancient times [See Herodotus on the Hellenic language, saying it is a branch of Pelasgic, pre-Greek and most probably non-IE]. Diodorus noticed too that the Samothracians whose ancestors had evidenced the Black Sea deluge, were using words belonging to that ancient language (probably a pre-IE Anatolian language) of those times.

Then you have other authors noticing similarities of various languages, such as Dacian and Thracian, Mysian with Lydian and Phrygian/or Paeonian and so on. There are many scattered comments on languages, but it is not clear how they explained the similarity. Herodotus described the view that Phrygian was the most ancient language in the world, so some people might have seen that as the proto-Indo-European of their time.

I do not remember how the relation to Latin was explained. I am sure there are comments about it as well, nevertheless by the Romans themselves. If I find more info on that, I will  get back to you.

Answer (score 10):

As I've [posted](https://www.quora.com/During-antiquity-did-anyone-in-Greece-or-Rome-recognize-similarities-between-Greek-and-Latin-languages-and-hypothesized-relationships-between-them/answer/Nick-Nicholas-5) in [The Other Place](http://www.quora.com), there was indeed a notion of Latin being a dialect of Greek, which a [recent paper](https://www.academia.edu/10153527/Aeolism_Latin_as_a_Dialect_of_Greek) has described as "Aeolism". The locus classicus for it is Dionysius of Halicarnassus:

> The language spoken by the Romans is neither utterly barbarous nor
>   absolutely Greek, but a mixture, as it were, of both, the greater part
>   of which is Aeolic; and the only disadvantage they have experienced
>   from their intermingling with these various nations is that they do
>   not pronounce all their sounds properly.

Greeks were well attuned to systematic differences between lects through their diversity of dialects, so they would have known something was up with the Latin–Greek relation. They might have noticed something similar further afield; but as I have also [speculated](https://www.quora.com/History-During-Alexanders-invasions-would-his-soldiers-have-found-Old-Persian-or-Indic-to-be-somewhat-familiar-sounding-given-their-closeness-to-Greek/answer/Nick-Nicholas-5) in The Other Place, they were very unlikely to have cared: Greeks were not terribly curious about the languages of barbarians. We certainly have nothing recorded about Greeks noticing similarities with any language other than Latin.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, we do not have any Greek or Roman texts discussing an eventual genetic relationship between Greek and Latin. There was however a heated discussion about whether language was “by nature” (physei) or “by convention” (literally: “by setting” thesei). You can read all about it in Plato’s “Cratylus”. If language is “by nature”, then it would follow that all languages have a common origin.